# A complex projective algebraic curve has no isolated points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given an homogeneous polynomial $f$ of degree $n$, I am trying to prove that the set $C = \{[x:y:z]: f(x,y,z) = 0\} \subseteq$ $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ cannot have isolated points.
That is, there is no $p\in\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ such that there exists an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ with $U\cap C = p$.

$\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ is the complex projective plane, with the topology induced by the natural projection $\pi:\mathbb{C^3}\setminus{0}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$.

This fact is not true for fields that are not algebraically closed, as in the real case. For example, the curve $y^2 - x^2(x-z) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$ has an isolated point at $[0:0:1]$.

Comment: Can you do this for $mathbb{C}^2$? That is, let $f(x,y)$ be a complex polynomial with $f(0,0)=0$ and show that $(0,0)$ is not isolated in $f=0$. If you do this, rest should be easy.

Comment: That's it! I know how to prove it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take $x,y$ as "parameters"and $z$ as your variable. Then by the argument principle the number of zeros in circle about $z$ is

$$n(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f^{\prime}}{f} dz$$

Now this is a continuous function of $x,y$ so an isolated point is impossible.